# Fail on build because of UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xcode13

I have an SDK was built in Apple Swift version 5.4.2, while the compiler is Apple Swift version 5.5.1:

[image]

So I followed the instructions and downloaded a toolchain Swift 5.4 Development Snapshot created on 23/04/2021. But now I'm getting another error:

> Failed to build module 'UIKit' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.5 (swiftlang-1300.0.29.207 clang-1300.0.28.1)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.4-dev (LLVM 439a44695a0534a, Swift 768e8d60459e7d8)'

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this? I didn't find anything on Apple forum, I have to run that SDK on a real device  (iPhone 13).

I'm using Xcode 13

Comment: The first error says the exact opposite of what you said; it says that you are trying to use something compiled with Swift 5.5 (presumably the ios 15 SDK) with a swift 5.4 toolchain. Try with a clean install of Xcode 13 and the toolchain that came with it.

Comment: For the second error try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295895/ios-simulator-builds-fail-on-m1-mac-with-binary-framework-module-compiled-wit) if you are using an m1 mac

Comment: The second error didn't work for me @Paulw11=/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duash.png